# Is there a "strict mode" for Apache Ant?

Tags: ant, properties, strict

If I have an Ant task like this:

```
<target name="default">
  <mkdir dir="${installer.config.installation.db.path}"/>
</target>
```

And the property referenced is NOT set, I end up with a directory (in this 'mkdir' example) being created with the literal name of (as a subdir of the 'basedir'):

```
${installer.config.installation.db.path}
```

Is there any way to enforce a failure if ANT is asked to resolve properties but fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this for all properties but you can check individual ones:

```
 <fail unless="installer.config.installation.db.path" />
```

The above will abort the script when the property isn't defined. It will succeed when the property is empty, though!

Answer (score 0):

the following works only with ant project-level properties. (groovy lib required)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="strict me" default="default" basedir=".">
    <target name="init-strict">
        <script language="groovy">
            import org.apache.tools.ant.PropertyHelper;
            def antProject = project;
            if( "#MyPropertyHelper"!=PropertyHelper.getPropertyHelper(antProject).toString() ) {
                def myPropertyHelper = new PropertyHelper(){
                    @Delegate PropertyHelper delegate = PropertyHelper.getPropertyHelper(antProject);
                    public Object getProperty(String name){
                        Object v = delegate.getProperty(name);
                        if(v==null)throw new org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException("The property `$name` not defined");
                        return v;
                    }
                    public String toString() {return "#MyPropertyHelper"}
                }
                antProject.addReference("ant.PropertyHelper", myPropertyHelper);
            }
        </script>
    </target>
    <target name="default" depends="init-strict">
        <mkdir dir="${installer.config.installation.db.path}"/>
    </target>
</project>
```